# Ignoring jquery validation for hidden blocks(div's)

Tags: html, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I'm developing a CodeIgniter application in which I have a form with multiple blocks, which have common or different fields. 
I have a select box and on selecting an option I'll enable/disable blocks(div's). One block will be visible at a time. I'm using jquery validation plugin to validate the form. I'm facing issues when I try to submit the form due to hidden block's mandatory fields. Can anybody tell me how can I solve this problem

```
$("#form").validate({
       ignore: [],
       rules:{
               company:{
                    required:true
              },
              location_name:{
                    required:true
               },
               address:{
                   required:true
               },
                city:{
                  required:true
                 },
                 pincode:{
                required:true
            },
            sender_name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                maxlength:50,
                firstletter:true
            },
            email:{
                 required:true,
                 email:true
            },
            mobile_num:{
               required:true,
               minlength:10,
               mobvalid:true
            },
            phone_num:{
               minlength:10
            },
            state:{
                required:true
            },
            type_of_sample:{
                required:true
            },
            manufacturer_id:{
                required:true
            }
          },
  messages:{
        company:{
            required:"Please select company name"
        },
        location_name:{
            required:"Please select the location"
        },
        address:{
            required:"Please enter the address"
        },
        city:{
            required:"Please enter the city"
        },
        pincode:{
            required:"Please enter the pincode"
        },
        sender_name:{
            required:"Please enter firstname",
            minlength:"Please enter atleast 3 characters",
            maxlength:"Maximum 50 characters allowed"
        },
        email: {
            required:"Please enter the email address",
        },
        mobile_num:{
            required:"Please enter mobile number",
        },
        state:{
            required:"Please select the state"
        },
        type_of_sample:{
            required:"Please select the type of sample"
        },
        manufacturer_id:{
            required:"Please select any manufacturer"
        }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
         form.submit();
     }
 });
```

Here manufacturer_id is in the hidden block which prevents me from submitting the form. Please help me out.

Comment: No jquery validate.js never validate hidden input. You have problem with other scenario. show you little more code here

Comment: Input fields are not hidden. Just the div is made hidden. It's difficult to hide/show every single field on every block, as there are more than 80-90 fields in the whole form. Can you please suggest me any other solutions on this.

Comment: You can see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ignore attribute from the function

```
$("#form").validate({
       ignore: [], //remove this attribute
});
```

so your code will look like

```
$("#form").validate({
       rules:{
               company:{
                    required:true
              },
              location_name:{
                    required:true
               },
               address:{
                   required:true
               },
                city:{
                  required:true
                 },
                 pincode:{
                required:true
            },
            sender_name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                maxlength:50,
                firstletter:true
            },
            email:{
                 required:true,
                 email:true
            },
            mobile_num:{
               required:true,
               minlength:10,
               mobvalid:true
            },
            phone_num:{
               minlength:10
            },
            state:{
                required:true
            },
            type_of_sample:{
                required:true
            },
            manufacturer_id:{
                required:true
            }
          },
  messages:{
        company:{
            required:"Please select company name"
        },
        location_name:{
            required:"Please select the location"
        },
        address:{
            required:"Please enter the address"
        },
        city:{
            required:"Please enter the city"
        },
        pincode:{
            required:"Please enter the pincode"
        },
        sender_name:{
            required:"Please enter firstname",
            minlength:"Please enter atleast 3 characters",
            maxlength:"Maximum 50 characters allowed"
        },
        email: {
            required:"Please enter the email address",
        },
        mobile_num:{
            required:"Please enter mobile number",
        },
        state:{
            required:"Please select the state"
        },
        type_of_sample:{
            required:"Please select the type of sample"
        },
        manufacturer_id:{
            required:"Please select any manufacturer"
        }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
         form.submit();
     }
 });
```

Reference [validate.js](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Comment: Your answer is right, but one can't use select2 in the form. Unfortunately, I've select2 elements in my form. So validation is not working. Anyhow, thanks, mate.

Comment: You can set name attribute in select element and use it in validation function.I will work.You can accept this answer if its working so it can be helpful to other people. @prabhu

Comment: Malek, name attribute is already specified. But in select2 plugin select box will be hidden so validation will not work. I tried a different solution.  Anyway, I'll accept your answer as it was for only hidden fields. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, there is a link for reference:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ":hidden"
  });
```

Reference is here: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js